# Make <li> appear depending on text being typed into text input

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to accomplish a feature where a user types in some text into an input field and while they're typing, `<li>` elements appear below based on what the user's typing in.

For example, there's a text input field and the user types in red - the following results would appear:

- red chair
- red apple
- red floor

Or if they typed in blue, the following results would appear:

- blue surface
- blue car
- blue computer

I currently have this code, however no autocomplete results seem to be appearing:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source : 
           [ { value: "http://foo.com",
             label: "Spencer Kline"
           },
           { value: "www.example.com",
             label: "James Bond"
           },

         ],
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
  });
});
</script>      
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" style="width: 75%;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery UI library?

Comment: Make the changes shown in my answer and with those scripts in place, it ll work just fine.

Comment: There were few syntax errors in your code. Let me give you a working JSFiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `jQuery UI JS`, `jQuery UI CSS` and `jQuery` libraries.

Also, your code needs some change. It should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: [{
        value: "www.foo.com",
        label: "Spencer Kline"
      }, {
        value: "www.example.com",
        label: "James Bond"
      }

    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
      window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="autocomplete" style="width: 75%;">
```

Comment: Like this: `$("#Your_DIV_ID").css("display","block");`